# Code crashing while allocating memory in the heap for holding the array of pointers to characters

Tags: c

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 256

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static void getList(char ***pppclist) 
{
    int n=0;
    int i =0;

    printf("Enter the number of items in the List: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //Array of Pointers to characters
    *pppclist = (char **)malloc(n * sizeof(char *));  //X50, x51, x52

    for( i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        *(pppclist[i]) = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char)); //*X50 = X100

        printf("Enter the %d items in the List: ", i);
        scanf("%s", pppclist[i]);
    }

}

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    char **ppclist = NULL; //array of Pointer to Pointer to character

    getList(&ppclist); //X1

    printf("The Entered List is:%s", ppclist);



    for(;;);
}
```

Hi all...Please help to debug the error in above program. I want to get a list of strings in get list function and print it in stack of main.I have allocated memory in the heap for holding the array of pointers to characters and characters.Some thing going wrong.Can any one help me?
PS: Dont mark as duplicate

Comment: So you are saying the bug occurs while printing the string??

Comment: @Michael Walz..I dont want to return from function.I just want to play with the memory in the stack of main function!!

Comment: 1) `i<=n` --> `i < n` 2) `*(pppclist[i]) = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));` --> `(*pppclist)[i] = malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE);` 3) `scanf("%s", pppclist[i]);` --> `scanf("%s", (*pppclist)[i]);` 4) Return `n`.

Comment: It helps me in error handling too

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It didnt work

Comment: @BLUEPIXY your point 2 shows error while compiling

Comment: compiler could not allocate memory for a void pointer!!

Comment: This `for( i=0; i<=n; i++)` is going to mean you go out of bounds on your allocated memory

Comment: @jeja Use C compiler, not C++ compiler.  See [DEMO](https://ideone.com/20xuqw)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Great that worked!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 256

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int getList(char ***pppclist){
    int n=0;
    int i =0;

    printf("Enter the number of items in the List: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //Array of Pointers to characters
    *pppclist = (char **) malloc(n * sizeof(char *));

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        (*pppclist)[i] = (char *) malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE);

        printf("Enter the %d items in the List: ", i);
        scanf("%s", (*pppclist)[i]);
    }
    return n;
}

int main(void){
    int i;
    char **ppclist = NULL;

    int n = getList(&ppclist);

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("The Entered List is:%s\n", ppclist[i]);
        free(ppclist[i]);
    }
    free(ppclist);

    for(;;);
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Great that worked!! Thanks a lot!! Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 256

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void getList(char ***pppclist, int *n)
{
  int i = 0;

  printf("Enter the number of items in the List: ");
  scanf("%d", n);
  *pppclist = (char **)malloc(*n * sizeof(char *));  //X50, x51, x52

  for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)   // using < instead of <= to prevent access out of bounds
  {
    // parentheses placed correctly
    (*pppclist)[i] = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char)); //*X50 = X100

    printf("Enter the %d items in the List: ", i);
    scanf("%s", (*pppclist)[i]);   // indirection correct
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    // main needs to return an int, required by C standard
{
  char **ppclist = NULL;
  int nbofitems;

  getList(&ppclist, &nbofitems);  // needs to return the number of items in the list
                                  // so we can print it

  printf("The Entered List is\n");

  // manually printing list element by element
  // a single printf cannot handle the whole list
  for (int i = 0; i < nbofitems; i++)
    printf("%d: %s\n", i, ppclist[i]);
}
```

- See comments for explanations.
- If you are using a C (not C++) compiler, you should remove the casts before `malloc`
- No error checking is done for brevity.

Comment: This is what I exactly want!!

Comment: @jeja it returns implicitly 0. The standards says so.

Comment: In c which has higher precedence () or [ ]??

Comment: @jeja that's another question. Ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks..Found the answer.( ) has higher precedence than [ ]

Answer (score 0):

First, in the getList function, when you want to access to the n item in the array, you have to wrap `*pppclist` in paranthesis, not `*pppclist[i]` because you should first dereference the pointer and after access to the n item.

Next thing, when you allocate your array, you should allocate one more item and set it to `NULL`. It's usefull for browse your array later.

Here is your code corrected:

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 256

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static void getList(char ***pppclist)
{
    int n=0;
    int i =0;

    printf("Enter the number of items in the List: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //Array of Pointers to characters
    *pppclist = (char **)malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char *));  //X50, x51, x52
    (*pppclist)[n] = NULL;

    for( i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
      (*pppclist)[i] = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char)); //*X50 = X100

        printf("Enter the %d items in the List: ", i);
        scanf("%s", (*pppclist)[i]);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    char **ppclist = NULL; //array of Pointer to Pointer to character
    int index;

    getList(&ppclist); //X1

    index = 0;
    while (ppclist[index]) {
      printf("The Entered List is:%s\n", ppclist[index]);
      index += 1;
    }

    return (0);
}
```